# How to use regex to find a specific pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I got a list that I intend to run through with my codes

```
myFunc(input); 
new data = myFunc(xexx); new data2 = myFunc (xdvdv);
func1(2 * 7, func2(3, 5));
func1(2 * 7, myFunc(3, 5));
new s3 = myFunc(xexx());
new s4 = 1_myFunc(xexx);
new s5 = addmyFunc(xexx);
new s6 = 1_myFunc(xexx);
new endtrip = myFunc_gos(xexx);
if (myFunc(a)) 
if (myFunc(&a))
if (myFunc(^a))
if (myFunc(*a))
```

and I should get

```
myFunc(<something but not everything>)
```

Here is an example

```
myFunc(input);          //should match only: myFunc(input)
new data = myFunc(xexx); new data2 = myFunc (xdvdv); //should match only: myFunc(xexx)
func1(2 * 7, func2(3, 5)); // should not
func1(2 * 7, myFunc(3, 5)); //should match only: myFunc(3, 5)
new s3 = myFunc(xexx());  // should not
new s4 = 1_myFunc(xexx); // should not
new s5 = addmyFunc(xexx); // should not
new s6 = 1_myFunc(xexx); // should not
new endtrip = myFunc_gos(xexx); // should not
if (myFunc(a)) //should match only: myFunc(3, 5)
if (myFunc(&a)) // should not
if (myFunc(^a)) // should not
if (myFunc(*a)) // should not
```

However I am having troubles writing the regex expression to obtain  this. here is my regex:

```
item.match(/([^\w]|^)strlen\((?:[^)(]+|\((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*\))*\)/g);
```

all is working fine other than I am still getting:

```
(myFunc(a)
```

Do let me know which part did I do wrongly.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are trying to read a source code, depending on your use case, an AST parser might be a better fit than regex. Depending on the language, you'd be able to find an appropriate parser via google search

Comment: `strlen` does not match any of your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex to parse a language is inherently error prone. Here is a regex approach if you can live with not supporting corner cases:

```js
[
  'myFunc(input);',          // should match only: myFunc(input)
  'new data = myFunc(xexx); new data2 = myFunc (xdvdv);', // should match only: myFunc(xexx)
  'func1(2 * 7, func2(3, 5));',  // should not
  'func1(2 * 7, myFunc(3, 5));', // should match only: myFunc(3, 5)
  'new s3 = myFunc(xexx());',    // should not
  'new s4 = 1_myFunc(xexx);',    // should not
  'new s5 = addmyFunc(xexx);',   // should not
  'new s6 = 1_myFunc(xexx);',    // should not
  'new endtrip = myFunc_gos(xexx);', // should not
  'if (myFunc(a))',  // should match only: myFunc(a)
  'if (myFunc(&a))', // should not
  'if (myFunc(^a))', // should not
  'if (myFunc(*a))', // should not
].forEach(str => {
  let m = str.match(/\b(myFunc\(\w+(?:, *\w+)*\))/);
  console.log(str + ' => ' + (m ? m[1] : '(no match)'));
});
```

Output:

```
myFunc(input); => myFunc(input)
new data = myFunc(xexx); new data2 = myFunc (xdvdv); => myFunc(xexx)
func1(2 * 7, func2(3, 5)); => (no match)
func1(2 * 7, myFunc(3, 5)); => myFunc(3, 5)
new s3 = myFunc(xexx()); => (no match)
new s4 = 1_myFunc(xexx); => (no match)
new s5 = addmyFunc(xexx); => (no match)
new s6 = 1_myFunc(xexx); => (no match)
new endtrip = myFunc_gos(xexx); => (no match)
if (myFunc(a)) => myFunc(a)
if (myFunc(&a)) => (no match)
if (myFunc(^a)) => (no match)
if (myFunc(*a)) => (no match)
```

Explanation of regex:

- `\b` -- word boundary to exclude any prefix
- `(` -- start capture group
- `myFunc\(` -- expect pattern `myFunc(`
- `\w+` -- expect 1+ word chars
- `(?:, *\w+)*` -- expect 0+ patterns of `,`  followed by 1+ word chars
- `\)` -- expect `)`
- `)` -- end capture group

Comment: @Ping Kee Ng: Does this answer your question? If so would you care to accept it? If not, please add some more details to your question.